# Bitmap to imageview in android

Tags: android

I am getting the following error when i try to set a bitmap object into an imageview. 
"imageView2 cannot be resolved to a variable" for the line : mImg = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.(imageView2));

CODE :

```
package com.example.ocr01;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //SETTING UP BUTTON AND LISTENER
    Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);
}

public void onClick(View v) {
      // do something when the button is clicked
    }

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}




//CONVERTING IMAGE TO BITMAP

/*public static Bitmap getBitmapFromURL(String xxx) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL(src);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.connect();
        InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
        return myBitmap;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}*/

    void create_bitmap(){
        //creating bitmap
        Bitmap source = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
        R.drawable.image1);
        //calling doGreyScale
        doGreyscale(source);
    }

    public static void doGreyscale(Bitmap src) {
        // constant factors
        final double GS_RED = 0.299;
        final double GS_GREEN = 0.587;
        final double GS_BLUE = 0.114;

        // create output bitmap
        Bitmap bmOut = Bitmap.createBitmap(src.getWidth(), src.getHeight(), src.getConfig());
        // pixel information
        int A, R, G, B;
        int pixel;

        // get image size
        int width = src.getWidth();
        int height = src.getHeight();

        // scan through every single pixel
        for(int x = 0; x < width; ++x) {
            for(int y = 0; y < height; ++y) {
                // get one pixel color
                pixel = src.getPixel(x, y);
                // retrieve color of all channels
                A = Color.alpha(pixel);
                R = Color.red(pixel);
                G = Color.green(pixel);
                B = Color.blue(pixel);
                // take conversion up to one single value
                R = G = B = (int)(GS_RED * R + GS_GREEN * G + GS_BLUE * B);
                // set new pixel color to output bitmap
                bmOut.setPixel(x, y, Color.argb(A, R, G, B));
            }
        }

        //converting bitmap object to show in imageview2
        ImageView mImg;
        mImg = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.(imageView2));
        mImg.setImageBitmap(bmOut);

    }

}
```

XML for the same :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:src="@drawable/image1" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="Button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

NB : I am a first time developer trying my semester project. Any kind of help is welcomed.

Comment: Why R.id.(imageView2) ?

Answer (score 8):

Try this:

```
    }

    //converting bitmap object to show in imageview2
    ImageView mImg;
    mImg = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
    mImg.setImageBitmap(bmOut);

}
```

instead of this:

```
    }

    //converting bitmap object to show in imageview2
    ImageView mImg;
    mImg = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.(imageView2));
    mImg.setImageBitmap(bmOut);

}
```

Comment: Whats the difference?

Answer (score 4):

`findViewById(R.id.(imageView2))` should be `findViewById(R.id.imageView2)`.

`imageView2` is a field on the class `id` rather than a method on the class `id`.

Comment: Removed the parenthesis but still got the error "The primitive type int of R does not have a field id" @Kingamajick

Comment: If you developing in eclipse after typing R.id. press Ctrl+Space it will list all the possible Id's

Comment: Have you re-built your R file since you added imageView2?

Comment: @vins - No 'default proposals' when i press ctrl space.

Comment: @kindamajick - How to re-build my R file? Please guide

Answer (score 0):

As said by Kingamjick

It should be findViewById(R.id.imageView2) it means find the view by using the id(id) in Resources(R) which you declared and named as "imageView2"

Comment: Removed the parenthesis but still got the error "The primitive type int of R does not have a field id" 
@vins

Comment: May be its not getting the Resource file, make sure there is gen folder in your eclipse project after building and R.java file in it.. If still problem there then try cleaning the project once

Comment: Already cleaned project and yes, there is a gen folder with R.java file. Still the error is present.

Answer (score 0):

try like this  `ImageView mImg = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);` this line write in on create method

```
 ImageView mImg = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
 Bitmap bitmapOrg = MainActivity.mImg ;     
 statusimage.setImageBitmap(bitmapOrg);
```

EDIT:

```
 Drawable drawable = mImg.getDrawable();
   if (drawable instanceof BitmapDrawable) {
       BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = (BitmapDrawable) drawable;
       bitmap = bitmapDrawable.getBitmap();
    }
```

Comment: Writing the line
    ImageView mImg = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
in onCreate did help removing the error but i why use MySipDetails.mImg ? 

Won't mImg.setImageBitmap(bmOut); do the job?

Comment: see edited code inplace of `MySipDetails` use your Activity name `MainActivity`

Comment: Cannot cast Image to Bitmap for bitmapOrg

Answer (score 0):

```
implementation 'com.chootdev:blurimg:1.0.1'
```

add this dependency and add this code to your main

```
package com.example.blureffect;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import com.chootdev.blurimg.BlurImage;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageView imageView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        imageView = findViewById(R.id.image);
        BlurImage blurImage = new BlurImage();
        blurImage.withContext(this)
                .blurFromResource(R.drawable.dnd_background)
                .into(imageView);

    }
}
```

it will blur the image a little